# RouteExistingFiles with ASP.NET and IIS static files issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6

I have ASP.NET MVC 4 application and has deployed it to Windows 2003 IIS6. I set wildcard to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll.

When I set routes.RouteExistingFiles = false everything works fine. But when I change to true image files return 404 error.

```
<!-- 
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/images/spinner.gif&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

On IIS7 it works good in both states.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.